# Override Material UI classes without changes in JSX

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Following is the example code:

**index.js**

```
import './styles/test.scss';
const App = () => {
      return (<Fragment>
              <div className="chip">
                <Chip />
              </div>
            </Fragment>
     );
}
```

**test.scss:**

```
.chip {
    margin-bottom: 16px;

    .MuiChip-root {
        background-color: 'blue';
        color: 'blue';
        border: 1px solid blue;
        text-transform: lowercase;
        display: inline-flex ;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 500;
        border-radius: 8px;
        margin-right: 6px;
        margin-bottom: 9px;
        height: 25px;
    }

    .MuiChip-label {
        padding-left: 6px;
        padding-right: 6px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }

}
```

It works perfectly. But now, I wanted to apply as "css in JS" style by using:

**import styles from './styles/test.scss';**

'MuiChip-root' and 'MuiChip-label' are core classes of Material-UI which I am overriding here. How to apply this modified styles in my JSX. **I do not want to make any changes in JSX to apply such styles (or wanted very minor changes which should be quick enough)**. (My project is huge and changing at both css and JSX level would be very time consuming).

Comment: Have you looked into [Global theme override](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-theme-override)?

Comment: this can be done very easily with `createStyles`